# Is there access to the `include` directive inside an active model serializer class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

Given the following controller code:

```
def show
  render json: @post, include: 'author', adapter: :json_api
end
```

Inside the serializer do I have access to the `include` directive?

```
class PostSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :title, :body, :foo
  belongs_to :author

  def foo
    # can I gain access to the include_directive here somehow?
  end
end
```

I have looked in `@attributes`, `@instance_options`, `@object`, `@root` `@scope` and `@serializer_class` (all the instance variables I can see with `pry`) with no luck.

I am using `active_model_serializers (0.10.2)`.

Comment: Yeah, you can use it using `@options[:include]`.

Comment: @PriyankGupta was that possibly available before `0.10`? I am looking at `@options` in my serializer and it is `nil`.

Comment: Try, `json: { post: @post, include: 'author', adapter: :json_api }`

Comment: @PriyankGupta, unfortunately the code implemented in this way never instantiates the serializer.

I tried specifying the serializer class as well while using this format, but no dice there either.

Answer (score 0):

The `include` option is passed to the Adapter. The adapter uses it essentially by passing it to `serializable_hash` in each serializer. So, you could redefine that method, inspect it, and call super

Otherwise I'm not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @BF4. For whatever reason my override never gets hit when called from the controller. Also this looks like it is marked as private api. I don't think we want to override a private method to gain access to this information.

I excluded the details of what we are trying to accomplish because I didn't want anyone to focus on what the code was doing, but rather focus on the includes directive exclusively.

I appreciate the help, but without having this information easily available we can just take a different approach. Cheers